# How do I find and remove compilers on my Mac?

Tags: macos, install

Some time ago, I installed Python, LaTeX, C, Perl, Fortran, etc. on my Mac for some college work. I think I used Homebrew to install at least some of them. Now I am not sure how to remove them as I don't can't find where they are. I went to the Library directory but don't know what to look for.

When I go to the Launchpad, I find all of these things regarding LaTeX. I am not sure if all of them are needed. Besides, I am not sure if they are just front end apps.

[image: The latex apps in the Launchpad]

Answer (score 1):

Those programs in the image can be removed by moving from Applications to the trash.

If you installed something from homebrew, the way of removing is the following:

```
brew list
```

This will show you a list of installed formulas. After the list comes to you, you have to select what you need to remove and use the command:

```
brew uninstall <formula>
```